# Javascript array with a mix of literals and arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

How can I create an json format in javascript

```js
var data = [
     {
         label: 'node1',
         children: [
             { label: 'child1' },
             { label: 'child2' }
         ]
     },
     {
         label: 'node2',
         children: [
             { label: 'child3' }
         ]
     }
    ]
```

I can add the 'node' using data.push, but how to proceed with childrens?
Thank's!

Comment: you need some reference to the pushed object.

Comment: Hello Mihai! Can you clarify what you are trying to do? It's a bit unclear.

Comment: I have a list of users with 2 different type of id, first one is 9 digit length and second it's 13. I want to create a json (in the format i have specified) where i have id with 9 digit as parent and id with 13 digit as children.

Comment: You should use `data[i].children.push(...)`, however you need to determine an appropriate value for *i* so that it is appended to the correct *children* array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, there is no such thing as a `JSON array`.  You are working with an array. JSON is a way to transfer data between systems.

You have an array called `data` that you need to push an object into...

so something like:

```
data.push({
    label: 'node3',
    children: [
        { label: 'child3' },
        { label: 'child3' }
     ]
});
```

Now.. you've got a problem at this point, because you are duplicating the `label` property, which is not allowed under ES5 strict mode.

Comment: I think the intention is to add objects to, say, `data[0].children.push({label:'child3'})`. But I may be wrong about that. ;-)